# Html2PDF table spacing issue after export as pdf

Tags: javascript, angular, html2canvas, html2pdf

I am using these options for exporting html to pdf of html2pdf.

```
html2pdf(document.getElementById('pm-pdf'), {
      margin:       10,
      filename:     'PM.pdf',
      image:        { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
      html2canvas:  { scale: 2, logging: true, dpi: 192, letterRendering: true },
      jsPDF:        { unit: 'mm', format: 'a3', orientation: 'portrait' }
    });
```

and this is the view of table in my application. and you  can see its well designed.
[Before export in pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9fGe.png)

But when i export it as pdf it get padding from top as you can see in the picture.[after export in pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BQjG.png)

Solutions I already tried.

1. removed all classes except 'row' and 'col'
2. removed table and implemented with simple label and adding border on
   it.
3. html2canvas.

*table code only

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
            <tbody>
            <tr class="prnt" *ngFor="let component of routineJobData.pmComponents[title]; let i=index">
              <td>{{component.label}}:</td>
              <td>{{component.value}}</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

Comment: could u provide the html table code?

Comment: @AlexYu code added.

Comment: the code seems alright, could u put the code on stackblitz? its better for debugging https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-html-to-pdf-example-answer?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: just look the difference your code is getting too. table looks different in pdf rows getting padding/margin from top that's what issue is.
BTW I'm using html2pdf

    html2pdf(document.getElementById('pm-pdf'), {
      margin:       10,
      filename:     'PM.pdf',
      image:        { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
      html2canvas:  { scale: 2, logging: true, dpi: 192, letterRendering: true },
      jsPDF:        { unit: 'mm', format: 'a3', orientation: 'portrait' }
    });

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: @MirStephen nope!

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same issue, it turns out for us it was a css reset style causing it.

Change this:

```
img,
svg,
video,
canvas,
audio,
iframe,
embed,
object {
  display: block;
}
```

to this:

```
img,
svg,
video,
canvas,
audio,
iframe,
embed,
object {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

if future readers are facing this issue still:
html2canvas renders css in its own way, and the workaround I found for this is add my own CSS on the onClone function based on how the export looks.

I had this table problem and in my case I solved it by selecting all the content inside  and pulling it a negative amount by its top like so:

```
 html2canvas(ref.current, {
    scrollY: -window.scrollY,
    windowWidth: document.documentElement.offsetWidth,
    height: height,
    allowTaint: true,
    onclone(document) {
      const tableDiv= document.getElementById(
        'tableContainer'
      );

      document
        .querySelectorAll('table span')
        .forEach((text) =>
          text.classList.add('!leading-none', '!top-[-7px]', '!relative')
        );

      document
        .querySelectorAll('table th span')
        .forEach((th) =>
          th.classList.add('!leading-none', '!top-[-10px]', '!relative')
        );
      tableDiv?.classList.add('bg-gray-primary', 'p-5');
}}
```